# Rigidbody vibrates or skips while moving I.e Left or Right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to a ThirdPersonCharacter, I was using the unity starter assets with the Character Controller but I realize that my character probably need a lot of physics so I decided to switch to Rigidbody, but now every time my character moves to the left of right or if `_input.move.x = 1 || _input.move.x = -1` the character with start vibrating while move, but if it moving forward or backwards, it moves smoothly. [Here's a video of what I was explaining](https://www.veed.io/view/6f49cf28-a2a9-4e2e-8130-960a02263c61)

```
public class ThirdPersonController: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    Vector3 direction;
    float speed;
    float RotationSmoothTime = 0.12f;
    float _rotationVelocity;

    void Update()
    {
        if(_input.move.x != 0 || _input.move.y != 0)
        {
            walking = true;
            running = false;
            direction = new Vector3(_input.move.x, 0, _input.move.y).normalized;
            speed = 1.5f;
        }

        if(_input.sprint)
        {
            running = true;
            walking = false;
            direction = Vector3.forward.normalized;
            speed = 3.0f;
        } else { running = false; }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
    }

    void Move()
    {
        float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + _mainCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y;
        float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref _rotationVelocity, RotationSmoothTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

        Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Eulee(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;

        rb.velocity = moveDir * speed * 100f * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be wrong but I think its to do with the `Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Eulee(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;` , since you're multiplying the Quaternion by Vector3.forward (which is (0,0,1) if I'm not mistaken) the rigidbody's velocity is always going to be (0,0,y) where y is the result of multiplying the `moveDir` by your speed your speed values, so technically it shouldn't be moving sideways AT ALL

Comment: @A-Fairooz That's just the rotation of the player base on the player's movement direction

Comment: But you're still setting the rigibody's velocity to a fixed value which in this case is (0,0,y) so any other movement that's happening with the rigidbody is getting overwritten by that line

Comment: I've fixed the error, all I needed to do was just turn on Interpolation at the Rigidbody